# Flex 4 skin shape tween effect

Tags: apache-flex, effect, shapes, skin, tween

I have two shapes in a skin:

1.Circle

> s:Ellipse width="20" height="20" includeIn="collapsed">
>       s:fill>
>           s:SolidColor color="#BBBBBB"/>
>       /s:fill>
>   /s:Ellipse>

2.Rectangle

> s:Rect radiusX="10" radiusY="10" width="80" height="20" includeIn="expanded">
>       s:stroke>
>           s:SolidColorStroke color="0" weight="1"/>
>       /s:stroke>
>       s:fill>
>           s:SolidColor color="#00FF00"/>
>       /s:fill>
>   /s:Rect>

I want to have a shape tween. This kind of shape tween that is possible in Flash IDE. Circle needs to transform into rectangle smoothly. Is it possible in mxml ?

Comment: I thought tweens were primarily for movement, not morphs; but such is not my expertise.  I think you'd have to write the transformation yourself, which could be tedious.  More info on Tweens in Flex here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf68e80-7ffa.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the Flash IDE can do it using the Timeline. You can't create it using code (unless you draw it manually), hence Flex doesn't support this feature.

**However**, I did find a Tweening library called [Tweensy](http://code.google.com/p/tweensy/) that says can do Vector Shape Tweens.  It's in beta right now and I've never tried it, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Not really.  I've been doing Flex for 3 years and never had a use for it.  Plus, it's not a Flex limitation, but a Flash limitation.